# Error (error C2064) , function in function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've tried to call function inside a function but no I've encountered some trouble while doing so, to be exact:

```
1>c:\users\yogi\documents\projekt_backup\v_4\rpg\rpg\mapa.cpp(548) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 6 arguments
```

This is the function I'm trying to do:

```
void Mapa::Mapy(float *xp, float *yp,int *dir,ALLEGRO_BITMAP *party,ALLEGRO_BITMAP *mapa1,float *moveSpeed)
{
    mapa1(xp,yp,dir,party,mapa1,moveSpeed);
}
```

This is an inside function:

```
void Mapa::mapa1(float *xp, float *yp,int *dir,ALLEGRO_BITMAP *party,ALLEGRO_BITMAP *mapa1,float *moveSpeed)
```

I've tried some of the solutions from this site and some others but nothing helped.

Comment: can you provide an example that compiles?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of one of your parameters, as it is called mapa1, too.
Just change the name.

Comment: Nice catch. I wasn't even looking at the name of the arguments, I was just counting them.

Comment: That was the case! Thanks.